how can i get this import to work in deno?
Using Deno 2.0.6 on Windows 11
I'm using civet 0.8.7 to produce *.js files and civet doesn't yet support things like:
import {assert} from 'jsr:@std/assert'
import {globSync} from 'npm:glob'

NOTE: this is NOT an issue with civet itself - it's regarding imports in deno
i.e. the jsr: and npm: isn't allowed. I thought that the solution would be to add these to my deno.jsonc imports key:
"@std/assert": "jsr:@std/assert@^1.0.8",
"glob": "npm:glob@^11.0.0",

However, when I try to import a file containing:
import {assert} from '@std/assert'
import {globSync} from 'glob'

I get the error message:
error: Relative import path "@std/streams" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../
  hint: If you want to use a JSR or npm package, try running `deno add jsr:@std/streams` or `deno add npm:@std/streams`
    at file:///C:/Users/johnd/vllu/src/lib/llutils.js:7:30

I thought that with the entries for "@std/assert" and "glob" in my deno.jsonc file (inside the "imports" key), deno would realize that these are NOT relative imports?
FYI, I did try running 'deno add jsr:@std/streams' as suggested. It runs fine, but I still get the error message above, so it didn't help.
FYI, here is my entire deno.jsonc file:
{
    // --- Comments and trailing commas allowed!
    "tasks": {
        "build:llutils": "civet --js -o .js --inline-map -c src/lib/llutils.civet",
        "build:compile": "civet --js -o .js --inline-map -c src/bin/compile.civet",
        "install:compile": "deno install -fgA src/bin/compile.js",
        "build": "deno task build:llutils && deno task build:compile && deno task install:compile && compile",
        },
    "imports": {
        "@std/assert": "jsr:@std/assert@^1.0.8",
        "@std/async": "jsr:@std/async@^1.0.9",
        "@std/cli": "jsr:@std/cli@^1.0.6",
        "@std/path": "jsr:@std/path@^1.0.8",
        "@std/streams": "jsr:@std/streams@^1.0.8",
        "glob": "npm:glob@^11.0.0",
        },
    }


I cannot reproduce this behavior. Could you provide a repository with the reproduction of the issue?

I also cannot reproduce this issue in a simple Deno app. So, either 1) I did something stupid or 2) it's been fixed in a more recent version of Deno. Personally, I think #1 is most likely. In either case, consider this no longer a problem. Thanks for looking into it.

The original issue is no longer reproducible, suggesting that it may have been resolved in a subsequent version of Deno, as evidenced by the release of 2.1.0.

I had this issue too. Today I upgraded deno and found out I had two different installations.
Default Terminal:
/Users/userName/.deno/bin/deno (version 2.1.3)
Vscode using homebrew:
/opt/homebrew/bin/deno (version 1.44.4)
I know you use windows. But for mac I needed to brew uninstall deno and then the correct version was available in vscode.
